# Oracle: column default value as another column from same table

Tags: oracle11g, sql-update

I'm using oracle 11g.

I have created table test_date

`CREATE TABLE test_date (str_date DATE, rtn_date  AS (str_date+90));`

I have inserted values of str_date

```
INSERT INTO test_date(str_date) VALUES(SYSDATE);
```

Now, it looks like

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test_date;
STR_DATE  RTN_DATE
--------- ---------
08-MAY-21 06-AUG-21
```

I want to update the value of rtn_date, but getting **error** like,

```
SQL> UPDATE test_date SET rtn_date='01-APR-2021';
```

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-54017: UPDATE operation disallowed on virtual
> columns

Is there any way to update the value if rtn_date?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can't update the `rtn_date` column directly like this, because it is only a virtual/computed column, based off the `str_date` column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks!! Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Sure; update STR_DATE and RNT_DATE will reflect that change.

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks!! I got your point. STR_DATE is starting date of rentals, and RTN_DATE is the return date. So I wanted to keep rent period 90 days, so if rent period exceeds, then I can update.